# Keras - Is it possible to train two unrelated models at once with one GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

With PyCharm you can have multiple instances of Python running the same file, so I was curious if there's any way to train the same model (or different models) twice, at the same time in two different instances.

I think it would be useful to be able to hit Shift + F10 on the file to start training, make a hyperparameter adjustment, and hit Shift + F10 again to start another completely separate instance of training and compare how they both train at the same time. However if one's already training, the second gives this error when the `fit` method is called:

```
2019-11-03 01:11:19.049817: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_100.dll
2019-11-03 01:11:19.243782: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:238] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
```

My guess is CUDA is having an issue with it being called twice at the same time or something similar. So is there any workaround for training two models on the same GPU at once? Or is that more feasable on CPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.3  # set 0.3 to what you want
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

Note, if you train model like CNNs it'll most likely use 100% of GPU which is probably not faster than wait for the first model to be finished first before train another model.
Also the possible batch size will be decreased, this might affect accuracy a bit

Comment: Wow, thanks! Set it to 0.2 and they're both training at the same time! Only takes about 1 second more per epoch too which is not bad at all